# Why object is taking last value in list?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

Why object is taking last value in list

```
ddd = [1,2]
master_list = []
for ridx in range(1):
    row_list = [] ; row_data = {} ; header_dic = {} ; 
    header_dic['background-color'] = 'green'
    row_list.append(header_dic)
    for metric_id in range(2):
        row_data['background-color'] = ddd[metric_id]
        row_list.append(row_data)
    master_list.append(row_list)

print(master_list)
```

Output coming :

```
[[{'background-color': 'green'}, {'background-color': 2}, {'background-color': 2}]]
```

Expected output :

```
[[{'background-color': 'green'}, {'background-color': 1}, {'background-color': 2}]]
```

Comment: @Stages It didn't raised any issue, because range starts with 0. therefore ddd[0] and ddd[1] exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move row_data in inner loop.

```
ddd = [1,2]
master_list = []
for ridx in range(1):
    row_list = [] ; header_dic = {} ; 
    header_dic['background-color'] = 'green'
    row_list.append(header_dic)

    for metric_id in range(2):
        row_data = {} 
        row_data['background-color'] = ddd[metric_id]
        row_list.append(row_data)
    master_list.append(row_list)

print(master_list)
```

And you will get the expected output:

```
[[{'background-color': 'green'}, {'background-color': 1}, {'background-color': 2}]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , Worked perfectly, If possible please explain :)

Comment: @akashk , in your example row_data was just ,one same object. Although you have placed it in a list it was still referencing same data. You can see that unique identifiers  are same: id(master_list[0][1]) and id(master_list[0][2])  Please up-vote if you liked the explanation :)

Comment: Thanks now I understood the problem, since my reputation is under 15, I am not able to upvote this :(

Comment: @akashk ,  glad that I helped !  Don't worry for the up-vote thing :)